# How to display the details about the selected option of a select box in Laravel using Blade?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I am a Laravel Newbie Some how I managed to display DB content in to a select box. What i wanted is that, i need to get data from another table based on the ID selected in the select box. My code is given below

Blade

```html
<h2 class="comment-listings">Subscriber listings</h2><hr>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Slelect a List:</th>
        
        <th><select class="form-control input" name="list1s" id="list1s" >
            <option selected disabled>Please select one option</option>
            @foreach($list1s as $list1)
                <option value="{{$list1->id}}">{{$list1->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
           
            </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<table>
    <thead>
    
    <tr>
        <th>Device ID</th>        
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Delete</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($subscribers as $subscriber)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{$subscriber->device_id}}}</td>                
        <td>{{$subscriber->list1->name}}</td>
        <td>

            {{Form::open(['route'=>['subscriber.update',$subscriber->id]])}}
            {{Form::select('status',['approved'=>'Approved','blocked'=>'Blocked'],$subscriber->status,['style'=>'margin-bottom:0','onchange'=>'submit()'])}}
            {{Form::close()}}
        </td>
        <td>{{HTML::linkRoute('subscriber.delete','Delete',$subscriber->id)}}</td>
        
    </tr>
    @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$('#list1s').on('change',function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var list_id = e.target.value;

    $.get('/subscriber/get?list_id=' + list_id, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
})
</script>
{{$subscribers->links()}}
```

Controller for populating select box

```
public function listList()
{
    $list1s = List1::all();
    $this->layout->title = 'Subscriber Listings';
    $this->layout->main = View::make('dash')->nest('content', 'subscribers.list', compact('list1s'));
    $subscribers = Subscriber::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
    View::share('subscribers', $subscribers);
}
```

This shows all the Lists and Subscribers.
Since i need to display subscribers of list selected in select box i have added a script at the bottom of the Blade and added other controller function at route to perform task based on the list_id passed from the script.

```
 Route::get('/subscriber/get', function(){
    $list_id = Input::get('list_id');
    $subscribers = Subscriber::where('list1_id','=', $list_id)->get();
    return Response::eloquent($subscribers);
});
```

But no changes are taking place, Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Edited my code, and was successful.

Blade

```html
<h2 class="comment-listings">Campaign listings</h2><hr>
<script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Select a List:</th>
        
        <th>
           <select class="form-control input" name="list1s" id="list1s" onchange="displayVals(this.value)">
            <option selected disabled>Please select a list</option>
            @foreach($list1s as $list1)
                <option value="{{$list1->id}}">{{$list1->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
           
            </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
    <div id="campaign">
    
    </div> 
<script>
function displayVals(data)
{
    var val = data;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get",
    data: { id : val },
        success:function(campaigns)
        {
            $("#campaign").html(campaigns);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Route

```
Route::any('/campaigns/get', [
    'as' => '/campaigns/get', 
    'uses' => 'CampaignController@getCampaigns'
    ]);
```

Controller

```
public function getCampaigns()
{
$list1 = Input::get('id');
$campaigns = Campaign::orderBy('id', 'desc')
->where('list1_id','=', $list1)
->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
->paginate(10);
return View::make('campaigns.ajaxShow')->with('campaigns', $campaigns);
}
```

I have a separate blade now (ajaxShow) to load when option changed in select box.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Campaign title</th>        
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Delete</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach($campaigns as $campaign)
    <tr>
        <td>{{{$campaign->template->title}}}</td>                
        <td>

            {{Form::open(['route'=>['campaign.update',$campaign->id]])}}
            {{Form::select('status',['yes'=>'Running','no'=>'Stoped'],$campaign->running,['style'=>'margin-bottom:0','onchange'=>'submit()'])}}
            {{Form::close()}}
        </td>
        <td>{{HTML::linkRoute('campaign.delete','Delete',$campaign->id)}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
{{$campaigns->links()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `eloquent` method implemented in `Illuminate\Http\Response` in Laravel 4 and above (I believe that method is only available in Laravel 3). But you can return a `json` response instead:

```
Route::get('/subscriber/list', function(){
    $list_id = Input::get('list_id');
    $subscribers = Subscriber::where('list1_id','=', $list_id)->get();

    return Response::json($subscribers);
});
```

Comment: I have changed it. Still, when I select a list the result remains same. Would you please check my script in blade file Mr. @Bogdan

Comment: If you access directly the URL for `/subscriber/list?list_id=1` (or whatever ID is valid) what is the response?

Comment: Also you're doing `console.log(data);` in your response callback, have you checked the browser console to see what it prints out?

Comment: I am afraid that the script is not performing any URL Call.

Comment: You're JS code looks fine as far as syntax and logic goes (this [simplified test](http://plnkr.co/edit/38yMOYwuF2vl4gNCw774?p=preview) using the JS code you posted, sends the AJAX request just fine). Have you checked the console for any errors that might interfere with the correct execution of that script (is jQuery being loaded successfully, errors in other JS scripts, etc)?

Comment: I have checked the console and it is working fine. But the problem is that the URL is not caught in Route, it is just displaying the file in corresponding path. How can I invoke the route? @Bogdan

Comment: You mean you have a actual file on the server that has the exact path and filename as the route definition (in `/subscriber/` a file named `list`)?

Comment: Yes there was. now i have changed to `/subscriber/get` now it is showing 404 error. But I have written a route `Route::get('/subscriber/get', function(){` why this route is not working?

Comment: If your URL path contains anything before `/subscriber/get` (like `/my/path/subscriber/get`) then either use the entire path in your script `$.get('/my/path/subscriber/get?list_id=' + list_id, ...` or use the [base tag](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-set-relative-urls-with-the-base-tag--cms-21399).